# Why is rootless docker still running as root inside container?

Tags: permissions, mount, systemd, docker

From a non-root `testuser` which is a non sudo account, I have installed a rootless docker following the instruction [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) (Ubuntu without package).

When I start a container and go inside it by running `docker exec -it my_container bash` then checking `whoami` I get: `root` instead of `testuser`. In addition, files and folders which are named volumes owned by `testuser` are not mounted and owned by `root`.
The docker daemon is running from `testuser` since I am running that daemon from a `systemctl --user`.

This is quite confusing.

1. Why is the docker not running as root inside the container?
2. Why are the mounted volumes all of a sudden with a different ownership?

I checked this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51973179/docker-mount-volumes-as-root), but it notes that when the daemon is running as root - that's normal, however that's not the case with my rootless setup.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the container is running under a different user namespace. root (0) in the container is probably mapped to your user ID on the host.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/